# logback.xml not scanned anew

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, logback

I've  configured the logback.xml file to be scanned every 5 seconds.

```
<configuration debug="true" scanPeriod="5 seconds">
...
```

Unfortunately this doesn't happen. What could go wrong?

The `logback.xml` file resides on the classpath of the Tomcat server. It's not inside the web application. It's parsed correctly on startup. I'm starting the server with Eclipse.

Comment: Please refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41762206/406896) if you are using logback 1.1.7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you forgot to set the `scan` attribute:

```xml
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds" > 
    ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have my configuration with <configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="10 seconds" debug="true">, but when I change the logback.xml file, it still "ignores" the change. Any idea of what am I doing wrong? I have already tried to log SEVERAL (more than 10k) messages to make sure it could reload, but nothing happened...

Answer (score 2):

Besides `scan` and `scanPeriod` another aspect has to be considered as well:

> Given that [ReconfigureOnChangeFilter](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/turbo/ReconfigureOnChangeFilter.html) is invoked every time any
>   logger is invoked, regardless of logger level,
>   ReconfigureOnChangeFilter is absolutely performance critical. So much
>   so that in fact, the check whether the scan period has elapsed or not,
>   is too costly in itself. In order to improve performance,
>   ReconfigureOnChangeFilter is in reality "alive" only once every N
>   logging operations.

For more information see http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#autoScan.