# Logback scan not working

Tags: java, debugging, logback

I am having trouble getting the auto scan functionality of logback to work. It doesn't seem to pick up the changes. I have added debug="true" to  section and reading it's output, all seems fine. It clearly says the logback.xml file is being monitored for changes every 30 seconds. I am at a loss as to why changes are not being picked up. Just looking for some guidance on how I can troubleshoot this further. Thank you.

I should mention that logback is logging to the file just fine, just that changes to logback configuration file are not being picked up.

logback.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds" debug="true">

    <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener" />  

    <property name="LOGS_PATH" value="C:\\Users\\****\\Desktop\\css_dev\\q_logs" />

    <appender name="scheduledTasksAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS_PATH}/scheduledTasks.log</file>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOGS_PATH}/scheduledTasks.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>25</maxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{MMM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{50} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="tasks" level="warn" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="scheduledTasksAppender"/>
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

Output to Tomcat log when web application starts:

```
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/C:/Users/*****/Desktop/css_dev/ProjectQ/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Setting ReconfigureOnChangeFilter scanning period to 30 seconds
|-INFO in ReconfigureOnChangeFilter{invocationCounter=0} - Will scan for changes in [[C:\Users\*****\Desktop\css_dev\ProjectQ\build\web\WEB-INF\classes\logback.xml]] every 30 seconds. 
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Adding ReconfigureOnChangeFilter as a turbo filter
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.StatusListenerAction - Added status listener of type [ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/C:/Users/*****/Desktop/css_dev/ProjectQ/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Setting ReconfigureOnChangeFilter scanning period to 30 seconds
|-INFO in ReconfigureOnChangeFilter{invocationCounter=0} - Will scan for changes in [[C:\Users\*****\Desktop\css_dev\ProjectQ\build\web\WEB-INF\classes\logback.xml]] every 30 seconds. 
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Adding ReconfigureOnChangeFilter as a turbo filter
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.StatusListenerAction - Added status listener of type [ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [scheduledTasksAppender]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [scheduledTasksAppender]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@298f464e - Will use zip compression
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@298f464e - Will use zip compression
|-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@298f464e - Large window sizes are not allowed.
|-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@298f464e - Large window sizes are not allowed.
|-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@298f464e - MaxIndex reduced to 21
|-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@298f464e - MaxIndex reduced to 21
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[scheduledTasksAppender] - Active log file name: C:\Users\*****\Desktop\css_dev\q_logs/scheduledTasks.log
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[scheduledTasksAppender] - Active log file name: C:\Users\*****\Desktop\css_dev\q_logs/scheduledTasks.log
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[scheduledTasksAppender] - File property is set to [C:\Users\*****\Desktop\css_dev\q_logs/scheduledTasks.log]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[scheduledTasksAppender] - File property is set to [C:\Users\*****\Desktop\css_dev\q_logs/scheduledTasks.log]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [tasks] to WARN
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [tasks] to WARN
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [tasks] to false
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [tasks] to false
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [scheduledTasksAppender] to Logger[tasks]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [scheduledTasksAppender] to Logger[tasks]
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@5b63e18f - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
|-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@5b63e18f - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
```

Comment: If anyone comes here with a configuration without "scanPeriod", be aware that the documentation of logback is currently incorrect. There is no default scanning interval. If you don't specify a scanPeriod, it will not rescan!

Answer (score 11):

Update (May, 2019) : The bug seems to be fixed now.

=============================================================================

With logback 1.1.7, `scanPeriod` needs to be explicitly mentioned. Otherwise logback will not scan for changes. This is due to recently introduced bug ([Here](https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1194?jql=text%20~%20%22scanPeriod%22) is the link).

Answer (score 4):

You logback.xml appear to be correct.

This is a behavior stated in the manual: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#autoScan,

> Given that ReconfigureOnChangeFilter is invoked every time any logger is invoked, regardless of logger level, ReconfigureOnChangeFilter is absolutely performance critical. So much so that in fact, the check whether the scan period has elapsed or not, is too costly in itself. In order to improve performance, ReconfigureOnChangeFilter is in reality "alive" only once every N logging operations. Depending on how often your application logs, the value of N can be modified on the fly by logback. By default N is 16, although it can go as high as 2^16 (= 65536) for CPU-intensive applications.
>
> **In short, when a configuration file changes, it will be automatically reloaded but only after several logger invocations and after a delay determined by the scanning period.**

Just try to log some more messages and see if the configuration is correctly loaded.

I hope this help you out.

Best regards,

Miguel

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of that and have tried logging well over 100 messages, still nothing.

Comment: try to add `<root level="TRACE"><appender-ref ref="scheduledTasksAppender" /></root>`
before your </configuration> in your logback.xml.

Answer (score 4):

Scanning does work actually, but the scanning is done on the logback.xml in the target/build directory, which isn't really helpful...

Comment: Any way around that?

Comment: I switched to Spring Boot & Spring Boot Devtools, together with log levels in application.properties it works very well. After any properties changes context restart takes only 1-2 seconds.

Comment: @FabianZeindl You can put the configuration file somewhere on the host and then tell Logback where the configuration file is located: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#configFileProperty

Comment: @Vadim Ferderer Are you saying that logback will pick up changes to logging.level.* properties in application.properties file during its rescan?

Comment: @JohnC If you use Spring Boot & spring-boot-devtools & mvn spring-boot:run – yes, logback will pick up the changes.

Answer (score 4):

I faced similar issue and the root cause turned out to be the way how I was initializing the logback.

**Initial Configuration - Not working:**

Below is the code which I used to configure logback using Joran.

```
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
configurator.setContext(context);
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(logConfigPath); // 'logConfigPath' is String path of logback.xml.
configurator.doConfigure(is);
```

In addition, my logback xml looked as below:

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="60 seconds">
....
</configuration>
```

Somehow, it was not re-scanning my changes in logback.xml.

**Troubleshooting**

So, I enabled debug mode in logback.xml by adding **debug** attribute as below.

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="60 seconds" debug="true">
....
</configuration>
```

When I ran the application again, I observed a log statement showing the root cause of the issue.

> 12:23:58,462 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Due
>   to missing top level configuration file, reconfiguration on change
>   (configuration file scanning) cannot be done.

This log is being logged by [ConfigurationAction.java](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/joran/action/ConfigurationAction.java) class when it is not able to find **mainURL** property in [ConfigurationWatchList](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/joran/spi/ConfigurationWatchList.java).

**Modified configuration - Scan working like a charm**

So I changed the code where I was configuring logback via `JoranConfigurator`. Instead of sending `InputStream` as parameter to `configurator.doConfigure(is)` I used the overloaded *doConfigure* method which takes file path itself as parameter.
Updated code looked like this:

```
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
configurator.setContext(context);
configurator.doConfigure(logConfigPath);// 'logConfigPath' is String path of logback.xml.
```

Updated debug log:

> 12:35:37,173 |-INFO in
>   ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Will scan
>   for changes in [file:/E:/Samples/config/logback.xml]
>   12:35:37,173
>   |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction -
>   Setting ReconfigureOnChangeTask scanning period to 60 seconds

Thats it!! Hurray :)

**EDIT :**

Looking at [GenericConfigurator](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/joran/GenericConfigurator.java) class, it turns out that, `mainURL` is registered with `ConfigurationWatchList` if we use `doConfigure()` method which takes `URL`, `String` or `File` as parameter.

Other three overloads of the method (with parameters `InputStream`, `InputSource` or `List<SaxEvent>`) do not register it.

Comment: Great but java's `file.lastModified` returns always the same time on my machine o.O

Answer (score 0):

With logback 1.2.3, config file rescanning also seems to silently fail if the path to the file contains a `+`. E.g. this works:

`-Dlogback.configurationFile=etc/logback.xml`

while this fails:

`-Dlogback.configurationFile=etc+/logback.xml`

Logback manages to load `logback.xml` correctly at initialization; it's just the reloading that fails in the latter case. If `+` doesn't work, it's possible that other characters are also problematic.

I went to file a bug on it but the JIRA instance linked from https://logback.qos.ch/bugreport.html seems to be currently nonfunctional.